# how to elegant use python dataclass singleton for config?

Tags: python, singleton, python-dataclasses

for some reason， I use the toml config instead of the .py config.

then, the singleton nightmare comes, continuously come up with `not init`, or `RecursionError`

is there an elegant way to use a python dataclass in project config?

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Config:
    _instance: typing.Optional[typing.Self] = dataclasses.field(init=False, repr=False)

    Targets: list[Target]

    FFmpeg: typing.Optional[FFmpeg]

    Whisper: typing.Optional[Whisper]

    Translate: typing.Optional[Translate]

    Srt: typing.Optional[Srt]

    Log: typing.Optional[Log]

    @classmethod
    def init_config(cls) -> typing.Self:
        if cls._instance is None:
            config = pathlib.Path().absolute().joinpath("config.toml")
            with open(config, "rb") as f:
                data = tomllib.load(f)
            log_config = Log(level=logging.DEBUG, count=0, size=0)
            targets: list[Target] = list()
            srt_config = Srt(overwrite=data['srt']['overwrite'], bilingual=data['srt']['bilingual'])
            cls._instance = Config(Targets=targets,
                                   FFmpeg=ffmpeg_config,
                                   Whisper=whisper_config,
                                   Translate=translate_config,
                                   Srt=srt_config,
                                   Log=log_config)
            return cls._instance


CONFIG: typing.Optional[Config] = Config.init_config()
```

or some other errors like below:

```
    if cls._instance is None:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'Config' has no attribute '_instance'
```

Comment: does it have to be a self-written dataclass? there are third-party libraries out there that have solved this problem already, even with similar-looking patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `functools.cache`.

```py
@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Config:
    Targets: list[Target]
    FFmpeg: typing.Optional[FFmpeg]
    Whisper: typing.Optional[Whisper]
    Translate: typing.Optional[Translate]
    Srt: typing.Optional[Srt]
    Log: typing.Optional[Log]

@functools.cache
def config():
    config_filename = pathlib.Path().absolute().joinpath("config.toml")
    with open(config_filename, "rb") as f:
        data = tomllib.load(f)
    log_config = Log(level=logging.DEBUG, count=0, size=0)
    targets: list[Target] = list()
    srt_config = Srt(overwrite=data['srt']['overwrite'], bilingual=data['srt']['bilingual'])
    config_ = Config(Targets=targets,
                     FFmpeg=ffmpeg_config,
                     Whisper=whisper_config,
                     Translate=translate_config,
                     Srt=srt_config,
                     Log=log_config)
    return config
```

An addition I like it the possibility to clear the cache to generate the config again. If this is useful usecase for you, consider to never store the returned config anywhere, "just" call `config().FFmpeg` for example.
The function call overhead is negligeable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no need to cache your singleton isntance in an `_instance` attribute. Just create your instance, and assign a top-level name for it, and make your code import *that* name instead of the class:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class _Config:    # "_" prefix indicating this should not be used by normal code.
    # Add relevant, publicly visible fields:
    Targets: list[Target]
    ...

def _init_config():  # <- no need to be a method, it is only going to be used once, and not everytime one needs the "Config"
    # it is only going to be used once, so no need
    # to check if anything already exists.

    # if any code that _knows_ what it is doing call this again,
    # just re-generate the config.
    config_path = pathlib.Path(__name__).parent.absolute() / "config.toml"
    data = tomllib.load(config_path.open("rb"))
    ...
    # no need for an esoteric, hard to reach name - 
    # just use a plain, easy to know what it is, name, like "Config"
    Config = _Config(Targets=targets, ...)
    return Config

# Public name: the configuration instance already loaded. Other code can use and import `Config` alone:
Config = _init_config()
```

Sometimes, simpler is better. Other times it is **way** better.

Also, I simplified the code setting the Path and reading the config file. But your call to `pathlib.Path()`  was depending on *from where* your program was being called to run - that is not good. I added the `__name__`  starting point so that it becomes deterministc - but depending on the file layout you don't show, you may need to add another `.parent`  there to get to the directory where the toml file actually is.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module named `config` that you import. Doing so, you’ll get the guaranty that it is a singleton.

```py
config_filename = pathlib.Path().absolute().joinpath("config.toml")
with open(config_filename, "rb") as f:
    data = tomllib.load(f)

Targets: list[Target] = list()
FFmpeg: typing.Optional[FFmpeg]
Whisper: typing.Optional[Whisper] = whisper_config
Translate: typing.Optional[Translate] = translate_config
Srt: typing.Optional[Srt] = Srt(overwrite=data['srt']['overwrite'], bilingual=data['srt']['bilingual'])
Log: typing.Optional[Log] = Log(level=logging.DEBUG, count=0, size=0)

del config_filename, data, f
```

If you want to prevent overwriting attributes, you can add `typing.Final[...]` to each attribute. This wont prevent users to change values, but it will warn them about the fact that it isn’t something they should do.